# Disabling Select Options on page load based on MySQL Query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Like the title says I have a select options input that I need to disable certain options based on if they have been added to the table twice, and if they have been added to the table twice already then disable the specific time option in the select dropdown.

In the example code below, in the table you can see there are already two entry's for 1/18/2017 at 12:15 PM.  So when I load the page I need to have 12:15 PM disabled in the options list when 1/18/2017 is selected for the date.  So if I loaded the page and I selected 1/18/2017 as the date, the option for 12:15 PM would be disabled.

I feel like I should be able to do this with a separate php file that would GET the data from the table with a QUERY and COUNT but I'm just not sure on how to attack this.

Example Table:

```
TIMESTAMP           Datepicker  Timepicker
2017-01-17 08:44:15 01/21/2017  12:00 PM
2017-01-17 09:52:00 01/20/2017  11:30 AM
2017-01-17 10:07:09 01/18/2017  12:15 PM
2017-01-17 10:08:58 01/18/2017  12:15 PM
```

Example Select Options:

```
<input class="dateselect" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Select Date">
                            <select class="timeselect" id="timepicker" name="timepicker">
                            <option value="10-15 Minutes">Select Time</option>
                            <option value="08:00 AM">08:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="08:15 AM">08:15 AM</option>
                            <option value="08:30 AM">08:30 AM</option>
                            <option value="08:45 AM">08:45 AM</option>
                            <option value="09:00 AM">09:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="09:15 AM">09:15 AM</option>
                            <option value="09:30 AM">09:30 AM</option>
                            <option value="09:45 AM">09:45 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:15 AM">10:15 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:45 AM">10:45 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:15 AM">11:15 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:45 AM">11:45 AM</option>
                            <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="12:15 PM">12:15 PM</option>
                            <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
                            <option value="12:45 PM">12:45 PM</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated all the stuff I'm finding online isn't quite what i'm looking for.

PHP Tentative File:

```
$host_name  = "xxxxxxx";
$database   = "xxxxxx";
$user_name  = "xxxxx";
$password   = "xxxxx";


$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

$sql = "SELECT Datepicker, 
   Timepicker

FROM shuttlerequests
   INNER JOIN (SELECT Datepicker
           FROM   shuttlerequests
           GROUP  BY Timepicker
           HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) dup
       ON shuttlerequests.Datepicker = dup.Timepicker;";

if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
return $sql;
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. I would create a PHP file that returns a list of times that are "unavailable" based on the input date parameter. Then, based on the list I get back, disable/enable the options appropriately. Try this sample:

**Javascript**

```
function getTimes() {
    var date = $('#datepicker').val();

  //REPLACE THIS WITH A CALL TO YOUR PHP FILE WHICH SHOULD RETURN THE DISABLED TIMES FOR A GIVEN DATE.
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getdisabledtimes.php',
    data: { date: date },
    success: handleTimes
  });
}

function handleTimes(obj) {
  //INITIALLY SET ALL OPTIONS TO ENABLED
  $('#timepicker option').removeAttr('disabled');
  //DISABLE THE OPTIONS THAT WERE RETURNED FROM THE FUNCTION
  for (var i in obj) {
      $('#timepicker option[value="' + obj[i] + '"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/3y69qygu/4/

*-notice the disabled times after clicking the "Get Times" button. The "Get Times" button in this sample simulates the selecting of a date in your code. That will vary based on your implementation (click, keyup, blur, etc).*

**Possible PHP (this has not been tested)**

```
$host_name  = "xxxxxxx";
$database   = "xxxxxx";
$user_name  = "xxxxx";
$password   = "xxxxx";


$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

$sql = "SELECT Datepicker, 
   Timepicker

FROM shuttlerequests
   INNER JOIN (SELECT Datepicker
           FROM   shuttlerequests
           GROUP  BY Timepicker
           HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) dup
       ON shuttlerequests.Datepicker = dup.Timepicker;";


$result = $connect ->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //CREATE AN ARRAY FOR STORAGE OF EACH TIME ENTRY (TIMEPICKER)
    $disabledTimes = array();
    //ITERATE THROUGH EACH DATA ROW THAT WAS RETURNED
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {
        //ADD THE 'TIMEPICKER' ENTRY TO THE ARRAY
        //NOTE: YOU MAY NEED TO FORMAT THE TIME STRING TO MATCH THE SELECT LIST. SHOULD BE IN THIS FORMAT: "08:00 AM"
        array_push($disabledTimes , $row["Timepicker"]);
    }
    //SERIALIZE THE ARRAY INTO A JSON STRING. THIS SHOULD OUTPUT SOMETHING LIKE "['08:00 AM','12:30 PM']"
    echo(json_encode($myArray));
} else {
    echo "[]"; //NO RESULTS HERE
}
```

Comment: First off Thank you for your amazing answer,  I'm trying to figure out the php file to get the duplicate entries for the ajax request and it's just not working.  I updated my question with the php file.

Comment: Are you looking for a serialize function for your data?

Comment: I'm not understanding "serialize function".

Comment: Basically, you will need to get the results from your SQL query and "serialize" it into a json string. I have updated my answer with a possible PHP solution. Please note, this has not been tested, and I am using your SQL query to extrapolate the column names in the database. It has not been tested. So that's that's my disclaimer. If you don't understand serialization, it's a fundamental part of what you are trying to do. I would recommend researching what JSON serialization is, and how to implement it in PHP. If you need anymore assistance, let me know.